# Pushforward/derivative of map between surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

If $f:M \to N$ is a smooth map between compact closed hypersurfaces $M$, $N \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, does it make sense to write the pushforward as $Df$, the total derivative? Because usually we require $M$ and $N$ to be open sets. If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, does the IFT hold true in the sense that I can write $(Df)^{-1} = Df^{-1}$?

Thanks

Comment: This is common in many textbooks, for example Guillemin and Pollack's "Differential Topology".   Yes, IFT holds.  See the text.